# Java comparing two string returns false although the strings are the same

Tags: java, string, file, arraylist

I am reading sentences from a txt file and creating an array of unique words. First, I read the file line by line. I split the lines with whitespace to get the words as a String array. Then if the words are not my unique words ArrayList, I add the word to the ArrayList. However, there is a couple of problems. The first one is that it also adds empty String to the unique words ArrayList. The second one is that it adds the same words 2 times, and when I compare those two Strings, it acts like they are not equal. My code is as follows:

```
    ArrayList<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        String []line = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0;i<line.length;i++)
        {
            if(uniqueWords.indexOf(line[i])==-1)
            {
                uniqueWords.add(line[i]);
            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println("0:"+uniqueWords.get(0));
    System.out.println("1:"+uniqueWords.get(1));
    System.out.println("2:"+uniqueWords.get(2));
    System.out.println("9:"+uniqueWords.get(9));
    System.out.println(uniqueWords.get(1).equalsIgnoreCase(uniqueWords.get(2)));
```

and output is as follows:

```
0:﻿
1:﻿adalet
2:adalet
9:
false
```

Comment: Maybe you got a trailing space somewhere

Comment: Please try: `System.out.println(uniqueWords.get(1).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(uniqueWords.get(2).trim()));` Of course, it shouldn't be possible to have duplicate words in your `uniqueWords` List... and you have `\\s+` in your split which should consume white-space... are there special characters there?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: PS: you can simply this using a `Set` instead of a `List`

Comment: Your string at index one contains a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is invisible but it makes this string different from the other string.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a look at the bytes those two `String` objects decode to you will see that they are not the same words:

1. The first String `adalet` converts to: `[-17, -69, -65, 97, 100, 97, 108, 101, 116]`
2. The second String `adalet` converts to: `[97, 100, 97, 108, 101, 116]`.

They probably use cyrillic characters or others that look like 'normal' characters but actually aren't.

---

<strike>**edit:**
More precisely the first `a` is a standard `a` for the second String and a cyrillic `а` for the first one.</strike>

**edit:** It's actually not a cyrillic `a`, my apologies. It appears to be an 'invisible' character instead. As khelwood pointed out correctly it's a `BOM`.

Comment: How did you arrive at the first byte[] from the OP

Comment: @user7 sorry? I don't exactly understand your question.

Comment: can you elaborate with small example

Comment: The string `adalet` in the post is exactly the same. How did you find the cyrillic one? Is it a guess? In other words, the first byte[] was derived from what string?

Comment: They are not the same. At least not for me. All I did was `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s1.getBytes()));` with a copy&paste on the strings. It was my guess from the start but that confirmed it.

Comment: Can confirm, copy-paste from the question shows an extraneous character before the first "a" in the first string.

Comment: It is not a cyrillic a though, that was a fault (in other words: bad assumption) from my side. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your string at index one contains a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is invisible but it makes this string different from the other string.

You can remove it while building your list.

```
uniqueWords.add(line[i].replace("\ufeff",""));
```